# rails active_link_to gem functioning on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, link-to

I'm using the Rails gem `active_link_to` for determining the active URL for menus.  It works great on straight forward links such as `'/controller/action'` but how can I do it similarly for particular param?

Ie `/controller/action?user=all`

Or is there a better gem that can provide this?

https://github.com/twg/active_link_to

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Regex functionality of the gem, depending on how your code is organized.

```
<%= active_link_to("Link Text", some_place_path, :active => /#{Regexp.escape(@param_value)}/, class: "blogYear") %>
```

You can execute code within a Regex with the above method if you are going to output the param or param value dynamically.